# Is ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() expensive to call often?

Tags: android, optimization, android-networking

I'm trying to figure out a strategy for my application, where I need to perform different network operations. My question is, whether calling `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` is considered a long-running and battery-draining operation and whether it's all right to call it often, or should I optimize my application's performance by applying another strategy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, did you get an answer if it is expensive call or not? If yes, how expensive w.r.t. caching results using broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 3):

I have used ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() in three apps so far. You might use a checkNetwork() method and call it to ensure you are in the correct state each time the user starts something that needs the network so that he or she can correct the situation. Beyond that, your error-handling might combine sleep() calls with network checks and connection management.  This means using about 30-gazillion permissions. But it would be a reasonable way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I thought about implementing this using a BroadcastReceiver, to catch broadcast messages related to connectivity and store the state in a variable, then just check it when I need to. It's a little bit more involved, cause my application consists of several Activities and I need to know when to register and unregister the BroadcastReceiver. This is why I wanted to know whether the method I've described is all right to be called as often as required.

Comment: Your idea may be better than mine. If your network needs are user-triggered, like uploading a file when he clicks a button, mine is okay. If your use is heavier, I think you have the better idea.